# What ORMs work in medium trust?

Tags: c#, mysql, orm

Environment: C#, MySql, GoDaddy Shared Hosting (medium trust).

Assuming the above environment, what ORMs will work in a medium trust environment? Also consider the following features:

- minimal code changes to the ORM library.
- minimal disabling of features to run in medium trust.

Bonus feature:

- fluent interface

There are a lot of ORMs to choose from. What would your selection be?

Comment: Which version of .NET?  I'm not aware of any mainstream .NET ORMs that don't work in Medium Trust.

Comment: I am targeting .net 3.5. After some searching, I will be trying nhibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a product called [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx), I currently use it on [discountasp.net](http://www.discountasp.net) without any problems, it supports a large number of database providers.  I use sqlite so i can deploy my website using a simple xcopy.  It has a great designer and is very intuitive to use.

> "LightSpeed happily supports Medium Trust environments."

If you want to try it out you can download the [express](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/thanks.aspx) version.